# Shall we delete default database under AWS Data Catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

We have many databases under AWS Data Catalog. We would like to delete some databases. We found a database with the name **default**. We thought it is the default database provided by AWS. Can we delete the database **default**?.

Is it a bad idea to delete the database default.